# fwui.log error while running this script

Tags: bash, scripting

I run this bash script in order to put all the files with the following format dated today in the same folder. for example here I want `2012-12-17_083213` to be my folder and then inside it I have the `.log` and `.log_stats` and etc with this name inside it?

But I am not able to get the script working. For example, if I try everything up until `dir=$(echo $i | awk '{split($1,a,"_"); print a[1]}');`
And then to test it, I did echo $dir, and that displays the following:
`fwui.log`
I searched and understood its about locks in the db but how to solve it?

This is the script:

```
#!/bin/bash  
tosend=""  
for i in *.log; do     
    dir=$(echo $i | awk '{split($1,a,"_"); print a[1]}');  
    if [ ! -d $dir ]; then  
        mkdir $dir;  
    fi;  
    cp $i $dir;  
    tosend="$tosend\n$dir"  
done  
for i in $(echo -e $tosend | uniq);do  
    echo Compressing $i  
    tar -zcvf $i.tar.gz $i  
    scp $i.tar.gz user@server  
done
```

and this is the file formats:

```
2012-12-17_083213_1.log  
2012-12-17_083213_1.log_stats  
2012-12-17_083213_1.logaccount_ptr    
2012-12-17_083213_1.loginitial_ptr  
2012-12-17_083213_1.logptr  
2012-12-17_093049_2.log  
2012-12-17_093049_2.log_stats  
2012-12-17_093049_2.logaccount_ptr  
2012-12-17_093049_2.loginitial_ptr  
2012-12-17_093049_2.logptr
```

Comment: It is more than just `user@server` in **your code**, right?  Because if there's no `:` (as in `user@server:` for the home of `user` on `server`) in the target spec of `scp`, it works like `cp`, only copying all your files to the **file** `user@server`.

Comment: @Renan I don't understand, Could you please give me an example?

Comment: @Renan ok here is the thing the problem is that i also have files in the fwui.log format that are being catched, these files can not be moved and therefore the error comes, what can i do to not catch them?

Answer (score 1):

first change that 1st awk line with:

`dir="$(echo "$i" | awk '{split($0,a,"_"); printf "%s_%s",a[1],a[2]}')"`

so that, in case they contain whitespaces, it will still work.

Then replace the "for i in" line with:

`echo -e "$tosend" | grep -v '^$' | sort | uniq | while IFS= read i ;do`

and add some "" around relevant places:

```
#!/bin/bash  
tosend=""  
for i in 20*.log*; do     
    dir="$(echo "$i" | awk '{split($1,a,"_"); printf "%s_%s",a[1],a[2]}')";  
    if [ ! -d "$dir" ]; then  
        mkdir "$dir" || { echo "ERROR during: mkdir '$dir'" ; exit 1 ; };  
    fi;  
    cp "$i" "$dir" || { echo "ERROR during: cp '$i' '$dir'" ; exit 2 ; };  
    tosend="${tosend}\n${dir}"  
done  
echo -e "$tosend" | grep -v '^$' | sort | uniq| while IFS= read i ;do  
    echo "Compressing $i"  
    echo REMOVE THIS ECHO ONCE TESTED tar -zcvf "${i}.tar.gz" "$i" \
    && { echo REMOVE THIS ECHO ONCE TESTED scp "${i}.tar.gz" user@server:/tmp/somedir/ \
         || { echo "ERROR during: scp '${i}.tar.gz' user@server:/tmp/somedir/" ; exit 4 ; };
       }
    || { echo "ERROR during: tar -zcvf '${i}.tar.gz' '$i'" ; exit 3 ; }; 
done
```

you may want to take out the "v" part in the tar, to save some display (once you know it works)

another way for the above:

replace my

```
for i in 20*.log*; do
```

with:

```
ls -1d *|grep '^[0-9]*-[0-9]*-[0-9]*_[0-9]*_[0-9]*\.log.*'| while IFS= read i ; do
```

Or simplify the grep :

```
ls -1d *|grep '^[0-9_-]*\.log' | while IFS= read i ; do
```

which should be enough (but could match a "./-_-1234.log.hahaha" file ...)

Comment: ok here is the thing the oroblem is that i also have files in the fwui.log format that are being catched, these files can not be moved and therefore the error comes, what can i do to not catch them?

Comment: I'll edit my solution to only loop on the relevant files

Answer (score 0):

You should start with `for i in *.log*; do` instead of `for i in *.log; do`; otherwise you only get files that *ends* in `.log`. Beside the fact that it may possibile be rewritten simpler, I cannot see any other problem in you script.

Comment: yes you are right but this is independent of the error. I don't know how to solve the error.

Comment: ok here is the thing the problem is that i also have files in the fwui.log format that are being catched, these files can not be moved and therefore the error comes, what can i do to not catch them?

Comment: Inside your loop, check for the value for the `i` variable; if it is a name you want to skip, just call `continue` this way: `if [ "$i" = "fwui.log" ]; then continue; fi`